# batch remove linebreaks from within .xlsx cells

Tags: excel, csv, vbscript, newline

I am currently trying to push content from a set of excel tables into a database. For that matter, i first try to convert said tables to `.csv` for further processing in python. However, the tables contain cells with multiple linebreaks, which apparently causes the resulting `.csv` file to be garbeled (newlines that do not contain any seperators). Manually removing all linebreaks prior to exporting to `csv` solves the problem. However, since there are 100+ files to be processed, i would like to automate this process with some kind of `vba/vbs` script (which i failed miserably to script for several hours).

How can i batch-remove all linebreaks from a bunch of excel files?

Comment: With VBA: you could open workbooks, import data into `List`, remove page breaks before you attempt to convert the text into `.csv` file. How to do that, well if you make a start on first opening the workbooks and adding tables into a `List` object and then posting your code here, we can help to finalise it for you

Comment: Not being a Windows guy, i dont see myself using VBA... I think i will first try pythons `xlwings` module and skip the entire csv part... But thank you nontheless :)